# exec/eval does not find imported class names

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to set up a smart way to save and load controllers in my project to and from json, I've implemented ways to convert my classes to dictionaries, that can then be written, and when I try to load them back in again, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaron/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-C/ch-0/201.6668.115/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1438, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/aaron/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-C/ch-0/201.6668.115/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/aaron/Workspace/github/mine/robinhood_tradebot/mod_test.py", line 28, in <module>
    data = JSONController.load(output_directory)
  File "/home/aaron/Workspace/github/mine/robinhood_tradebot/tradebot/controllers/json_controller.py", line 81, in load
    module = eval(dtype + ".from_dict(d['data'])")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'TestQSM' is not defined
```

for all intents and purposes, I've simplified my code a bit to make it easier to replicate the issue, there are 2 files: **edit** I added the exportation script to `TestQSM`

1. mod_test.py

```py
import json, os, inspect, time
import os.path as path

from json_controller import JSONController


output_directory = '/tmp/robin_test'


class TestQSM:
  def __init__(self):
      self.name = 'test'

  @property
  def dict(self) -> dict:
      return {'name': self.name}

  def save_json(self, dirname: str):
      d = {'dtype': str(type(self).__name__),
           'package': str(inspect.getfile(self.__class__)),
           'data': self.dict}
      with open(path.join(dirname, 'state.json')) as fp:
          json.dump([d], fp)

  @staticmethod
  def from_dict(d: dict) -> object:
      sm = TestQSM()
      return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
  obj = TestQSM()
  obj.save_json(output_directory)

  data = JSONController.load(output_directory)
```

2. json_controller.py

```py
import os.path as path
import os, json, inspect, sys
import importlib.util as imputil

class JSONController:
  @staticmethod
  def load(dirname: str):
      print('Loading state data')

      modules = []

      if not path.exists(dirname):
          os.makedirs(dirname, exist_ok=True)

      with open(path.join(dirname, state_save_file), mode='r') as fp:
          data = json.load(fp)

      for d in data:
          dtype = d['dtype']
          spec = imputil.spec_from_file_location(dtype, d['package'])
          mod = imputil.module_from_spec(spec)
          sys.modules[dtype] = mod
          spec.loader.exec_module(mod)

          module = eval(dtype + ".from_dict(d['data'])")
          modules.append(module)
```

I've tried several ways to replicate the problem, and I've found that only when the file reading takes place in a different python file, does the error occur, why is that?

Is there any way to make a workaround?

Comment: `eval()` inherits the scope in which it was called. You need to either import `TestQSM` in that scope, or include module information in your JSON, then dynamically import classes using it.

Comment: by module information, do you mean the actual class definition, or like an import statement string?

Comment: The import path of the module in which the class is defined. Check out `importlib`.

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how to get the full package name of some arbitrary class programmatically would you?

Comment: @robinsax that didn't work, I updated my question with my latest attempt using your idea, I found some bugs, though, I'll have it ready in a few minutes, it's ready

Comment: @robinsax I've updated my code, it should be good to go now

Comment: I figured it out, you have to load the module name, then import your class using `exec`

Answer (score 0):

Fron @robinsax stated

> `eval()` inherits the scope in which it was called. You need to either import `TestQSM` in that scope, or include module information in your JSON, then dynamically import classes using it.

To do this, I had to add the following section to the json loader

```py
@staticmethod
def load(dirname: str):
    print('Loading state data')

    modules = []

    if not path.exists(dirname):
        os.makedirs(dirname, exist_ok=True)

    with open(path.join(dirname, state_save_file), mode='r') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)

    for d in data:
        dtype = d['dtype']
        spec = imputil.spec_from_file_location(d['package'], d['path'])
        mod = imputil.module_from_spec(spec)
        sys.modules[d['package']] = mod
        spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
        exec('from {} import {}'.format(d['package'], dtype))

        module = eval("{}.from_dict(d['data'])".format(dtype))

        modules.append(module)
```

Note that you need to import the package name **AND** the class.

1. Import the package

```py
spec = imputil.spec_from_file_location(d['package'], d['path'])
mod = imputil.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[d['package']] = mod
spec.loader.exec_module(mod)
```

2. Import the class

```py
exec('from {} import {}'.format(d['package'], dtype))
```